# Querying Column Name as Variable Using Tableau Custom SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-desktop

I am building a lookup tool that will take Column Name and Table Name as inputs from Tableau as Parameters, and plug those in to Tableau Custom SQL as Parameter values, but I cannot find a way to make the Column Name dynamic in the select query.

Here is the idea:

```
Select ParameterColumnName
FROM TABLE(ParameterTableName)
```

I have investigated Snowflake's "IDENTIFIER" commands, but those seem to work only in the FROM clause of the query. I have tested with a static column name and dynamic table name and that works fine.
I have also explored setting variables with the parameter column name values, but I cannot seem to use "SET" in Tableau Custom SQL--it does not recognize SET. Appreciate any pointers.

***Update**:* [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470863/how-to-assign-variables-in-tableau) appears to address why I cannot set variables from Custom SQL, but if that's not it, let me know!

Comment: What about using a [stored procedure](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript.html) where you pass the ColumnName and TableName as arguments to the procedure?

Comment: @Sergiu Since SP's don't return a recordset, I don't think that's what is needed.  IDENTIFIER is likely the answer, but I'm not sure how that translates in Tableau.